# EOSIO - Error 3120006: No available wallet

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio.token, rpc, keosd

I have created wallet using RPC API.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8891/v1/wallet/create
```

Here, **keosd** run on port number 8891 and **nodeos** run on 8892.

Then, I have **opened**, **unlock** and **import key** into wallet using RPC APIs.

After that I am trying to create **eosio** account using following command.

```
cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:8892 create account eosio eosio.token my_key my_key
```

But i got an exception :

```
"/usr/local/eosio/bin/keosd" launched
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open
```

Then I have checked wallet list that showing wallet name with unlock. So, Why am I getting wallet not exist error?

What am I doing wrong here? How to solve that error? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

```
cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:8892 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8891 create account eosio eosio.token your_key your_key
```

Comment: Thank you. it's works.